# .htaccess multiple subdomain to folder redirection using END flag

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm setting up a website for a user and it's become apparent that they have lots of subdomains which were previously directed to specific folders. I'd rather find some way that they can manage this themselves by creating the relevant directories rather than me keep adding virtual hosts or altering `.htaccess` rules each time they want to add/change them.

As such, I came up with the idea of using a catch-all vhost, and using `.htaccess` to direct the subdomain to the correct folder.

Now I know similar questions have been asked, but I'm trying to achieve this with a single ruleset, and without performing a full HTTP redirect.

Currently I have the below rules, but I'm getting a strange problem

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,END,QSA]
```

Basically the idea is to avoid `.well-known` so that LetsEncrypt can use the document root to get certs for any sub domain, avoid `www.` which should use the standard path, but then match and redirect any other subdomain.

Without `END` this predictably ends with a server error and an `exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects` message in the log. This at least seems to confirm it's matching and redirecting though.

However, when using the `END` keyword, as far as I understand it, the rewrite should only happen once; I'm seeing strange behaviour though.

For a specific path, it seems to work fine

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: journey.example.co.uk

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
... snip content from /journey/index.html ...
```

But if I don't give a path, it seems like it's processing the redirect twice.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: journey.example.co.uk

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

... snip ...
<p>The requested URL /journey/journey/index.html was not found on this server
... snip ...
```

Given the use of `%1`, which should be the first part of the hostname, `$1`, which should be either just a `/` or empty in this case, I don't see how it's ending up with `journey` twice in the rewritten path.

Answer (score 2):

Think I might of managed to get this working myself by looking through the rewrite flags documentation for the 10th time and finding this.

```
nosubreq|NS Causes a rule to be skipped if the current request is an internal sub-request.
```

The further documentation talks about SSI which isn't relevant to my issue, but it does go on to mention the following:

```
Also, when mod_dir tries to find out information about possible directory default files (such as index.html files), this is an internal subrequest, and you often want to avoid rewrites on such subrequests
```

My understanding is that the request for `/` causes `mod_dir` to make a subrequest for `index.html`, which results in two requests, and two rewrites.

Adding the above flag to the rule seems to be working, at least in a few quick tests. As such the following rules seem to allow for redirecting any subdomain to the same-named directory under document root.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [END,NS]
```

Comment: Just a couple of minor things... You don't need the `L` flag if you are using the `END` flag. And the `QSA` flag is not required in this instance. The query string is passed through by default, unless you explicitly include a query string in the _substitution_.

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks, that makes sense. I also didn't realise that the query string was passed through already unless there is one specific on the rewrite destination.